# Equivalent definitions of filtered categories

Tags: category-theory

A category $C$ is said to be filtered if

1. $\mathrm{obj}(C)$ is not empty.
2. For every two objects $i,j\in C$, there exist arrows $i\to k$ and $j\to k$.
3. For every $u,v\colon a\to b$, there exists an arrow $w\colon b\to e$ such that $wu=wv$.

This definition is equivalent to (or at least implies) the fact that every finite diagram in $C$ has a cocone. Here, cocone means a cone $\tau\colon F\Rightarrow c$, where $F\colon J\to C$ is a functor and $J$ is finite. I am trying to prove this result directly from the above axioms.

My strategy goes as follows:

I observe that the diagram in axiom 3 is like a coequalizer except that $w\colon b\to e$ is not universal. Similarly, the diagram in axiom 2 is like a coproduct. Therefore, I tried to mimic the proof of the following fact. After all, all I need is a cocone, not a limiting cocone.

> **Fact**: A category has finite colimits if it has an initial object, coequalizers, binary coproducts.

However, I really need the following fact which I cannot prove using the above axioms.

Let $a\to d,b\to d$ be two arrows. If $a\to e, b\to e$ are another two arrows, then there exists an arrow $d\to e$ such that every triangle commutes.

So, will my strategy work? If not, how do I approach this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you're going about your strategy, but the basic idea is right.  You shouldn't try to imitate the construction of colimits from coproducts and coequalizers too literally--as you may have observed, you're not going to be able to construct the pair of maps between the "coproducts" that you wish to coequalize.  However, once you've constructed a "coproduct", you can use axiom 3 repeatedly to coequalize all the maps in the diagram one at a time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how to coequalize those maps in the diagram of "coproducts"?

Comment: Given an object $c$ with a map $F(j)\to c$ for each $j\in J$ and a map $j\to k$ in $J$, you can use (3) to find a map $c\to c'$ which coequalizes the map $F(j)\to c$ and the composition $F(j)\to F(k)\to c$.  Replacing $c$ with $c'$ and repeating this for every map in $J$, you get a cocone.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!